# How do I transfer my android app to another Google Play Console account?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, mobile-application

Example: Suppose I have created a Google Play Console account with my Gmail id and published an app on it. Now the app has about 100k downloads. Now I created a second Google Play Console account with another Gmail id. Is there a way to transfer my app to this new Google Play Console account without losing those 100k downloads and ratings/reviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I searched and found that it is possible to transfer apps ownership to another account. In the main screen/dashboard of the Google Play Console in the left hand side panel, under Setup option, the last option says "App Transfer". There you can fill a form and transfer your apps ownership to another account all while not losing your downloads, ratings, and reviews.

Comment: Does transferred app will be removed from the first account?